# The cv2.HoughLinesP isn't returning any lines

Tags: python, opencv, houghlinesp

I am writing a program using opencv with python to run on raspberry pi, i was testing something and when i send an imaged after doing canny with clearly some edges in it to the HoughLinesP method

```
lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(
        cropped_image,
        rho=1,
        theta=np.pi / 60,
        threshold=160,
        lines=np.array([]),
        minLineLength=40,
        maxLineGap=25
    )
```

the problem is the lines = None, there were no lines detected and i can't figure out why, i tried to change the parameters but nothing changed

Comment: Could you add your image you're applying houghlines on?

Comment: unfortunately i can't, i guess because of the new membership or smth, i will try to upload it from an other account